# a problem of transformation in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Show by means of transformation

$$w=\frac{(z-ic)^2}{(z+ic)^2}$$

that upper half of $w$-plane correspond to interior of a certain semi circle in $z$-plane, where $z$ is a complex no.

I solve it by splitting w in real & imaginary parts I got

$$u=\frac{x^2+y^2-c^2}{(x^2+(y+c)^2)^2},\quad v=\frac{-4cx(x^2+y^2-c^2)}{(x^2+(y+c)^2)^2}$$
but after then I am unable to solve further

Answer (score 1):

Decompose the map,

$$f\colon z \mapsto \zeta = \frac{z-ic}{z+ic} \mapsto w = \zeta^2 = \left(\frac{z-ic}{z+ic}\right)^2.$$

The two parts the map is composed of should be somewhat familiar, and you should now be able to invert it (note, there are two branches of $f^{-1}$ on the upper half plane) to find which domain(s) in the plane are mapped to the upper half plane by $f$.

Comment: i find some difficulty bcoz .is there some simpler way to solve it.i am a teacher & i have to explain my answer to my students

Comment: If the students know the most important facts about Möbius transformations, it shouldn't be difficult. The square root that maps the half-plane to the quadrant should be straightforward anyway, and then you invert the Möbius transformation to see to what half-disk the quadrant goes in $f^{-1}$. If Möbius transformations aren't yet known, it's of course more difficult, but solving $\zeta = \frac{z-ic}{z+ic}$ for $z$ should be within reach.

Comment: THANKS & i find the another simpler way.would u like to know about that or if i was wrong u can correct me.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that you asked for a reply. Yes, please tell what you found.

Comment: can isend my answer u via mail.here i found some difficulty to type my answer good night

Comment: I'm not so keen on giving my email address out.  Could you put it on dropbox or somewhere if you can't type it out here?